# Trying to get info from a textfile and split the info in an array

Tags: java, arrays

I'm having a problem with splitting a textfile and getting the info from the textfile to an array so that i can choose the index that I want to print.
The textfile is formatted like this:

```
X;25
Y;15
```

What I want to do is split the file so I can print X 25 and Y 15 or if I can get it to print just everything separately: `X, 25, Y, 15`

This is my code, I've tried very many different variations but right now I'm completely stuck. I've been tipped about `HashMap` but have no idea how to do that.
Anybody who can fix my problem?

```
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(textfile)));

StringBuilder SB = new StringBuilder();
String assign = BR.readLine();

while((assign = BR.readLine()) != null) {
    if (assign.contains(";")) {
        SB.append(assign);   
        String assignment = SB.toString();
        String[] splitting = assignment.split(";");

        for (String s : splitting) {
            System.out.println(s);
        }  
    }
}
```

Comment: If you format is `X;25Y;15`, then why do you split with `;`? The result would be `X, 25Y, 25`? But the first question should be: why is there no delimiter between the value of `X` and the letter `"Y"`? And you know that you ignore the first line of your file, right?

Comment: Thats how the textfile is formatted. I cant change the textfile. Where and why do I ignore the first line. Cus the only thing i get printed is Y 15

Comment: Here: `String assign = BR.readLine();`. You read the first line and do nothing with it. And your last sentence sounds like, that your file format is not `X;25Y;15`, more likely it is `X;25\nY;15`. So please update your question and provide proper information. For example, provide a part of your textfile you're trying to read and evaluate.

Comment: Thats the only thing in the textfile: X;25
Y;15 I opened the textfile with notepad and it show without \n. But when I open it with in my prog (NetBeans) it's formatted as you say.

Comment: You're on Windows, right? Notepad won't break the line if there is a single `\n`. It expects `\r\n`. Try to use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/). This program is much more advanced.

Comment: Yeah exactly im on win. Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(textfile)));

String assign;

while((assign = BR.readLine()) != null){

    String[] splitting= assign.split(";");

    for(int i =0; i < splitting.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(splitting[i]);
    }  

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the whole StringBuilder complication? (not tested)

```
BufferedReader BR = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(new File(textfile)));

        String assign = BR.readLine(); //skips first line (if you have a header)

        while((assign = BR.readLine()) != null){

            String[] splitting= assign.split(";");

            for(int i =0; i < splitting.length; i++) {
                System.out.println(splitting[i]);
            }  

        }
```

Comment: Only get [Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742
[Ljava.lang.String;@15db9742 printed out

Comment: With System.out.println(splitting);

Comment: @hjem use `System.out.println(splitting[i]);`

Comment: System.out.println(splitting[i]); gets me the same print as before:
Y

15


the X 25 is missing

Comment: @hjem As I said in my comment under your question, you're ignoring the first line, that contains `X;25`.

Comment: @Tom yes i see but i don't get how i can change it? What should I use instead of readLine?

Comment: @hjem just remove the first `BR.readLine()`: `String assign;`. Calling `#readLine` in the `while` loop is enough.

Comment: ups, obviously the `s` should have been `splitting[i]`.

Answer (score 0):

If you like to retrieve the content of the file (and not just print it), then you can try the code below. There I use a [`Map`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) to store the file content and print it later.

```
private static final String DELIMITER = ";"; // define a constant for the used delimiter

public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final Map<String, Integer> fileContent = readFile("test.txt");
    System.out.println(fileContent);
}

public static Map<String, Integer> readFile(final String fileName) {
    final Map<String, Integer> content = new HashMap<>(); // define a map for the file content
    // try-with-resources statement so the file will be closed safely
    try (final FileReader fileReader = new FileReader(new File(fileName));
         final BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader)) {
        String line;
        while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
            if (line.contains(DELIMITER)) {
                final String[] parts = line.split(DELIMITER);
                // the second value is an integer, so we need to convert it
                content.put(parts[0], Integer.parseInt(parts[1]));
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // handle exception a bit more, if you like ...
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return content;
}
```

The output will be:

```
{X=25, Y=15}
```

That means the map `fileContent` contains the keys `"X"` and `"Y"` and their values are `25` and `15`. If you like to get the value for `"X"`, then use `int valueX = fileContent.get("X");`.

Your current code won't close the opened file reader, that is why I've wrapped my code in a [try-with-resources statement](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html). It will handle that for me.

If there occurs an `IOException` (file not found, or file couldn't be read, or something like this), then I currently just print the stacktrace. You can handle this case differently, if you like: [tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/handling.html).

Try to play with the above code to see how it works. I hope it helps you.